# Check if column exists in another table - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables (A and B) wherein I wanted to select both rows that satisfies the condition:

```
if a.time and b.time <= 12 hours 
AND A.col1 = B.col2 AND A.col2 = B.col1
```

A

```
  |Date    | Time  | Col1 | Col2
  |20150818| 000256| AAAA | BBBB
  |20150818| 000456| AAAA | CCCC
```

B

```
  |Date    | Time  | Col1 | Col2
  |20150820| 000359| BBBB | AAAA
  |20150818| 000259| BBBB | AAAA
  |20150818| 001459| CCCC | AAAA
```

Expected output

```
  |Date    | Time  | Col1 | Col2 |Date    | Time  | Col1 | Col2
  |20150818| 000256| AAAA | BBBB |20150818| 000259| BBBB | AAAA
  |20150818| 000456| AAAA | CCCC |20150818| 001459| CCCC | AAAA
```

Since I am new to SQL,

```
select * 
from A 
where exists 
      (select 1 from B where B.Col1 = A.Col2 and B.Col2 = A.Col1)
```

which displays only rows from table A without considering the time.

Comment: what database are you using? this is important for proposing a relevant solution

Comment: what is the `Time` column format?

Comment: I don't understand this completely. "a.time and b.time <= 12 hours"? So both must be <= 001200? Then why is 001459 in your results? And why do you combine the first record of A with the first record of B only? Doesn't the second B Record also match?

Comment: @Used_By_Already Oracle Database 11g

Comment: Okay, so time is a string containing HHMMSS. Consequently '001459' matches your criteria. But still I'd expect 3 result records: A000256-B000359, A000256-B000259, A000456-B001459. Or shall the date be taken into consideration? Is  "a.time and b.time <= 12 hours" even supposed to mean something like "the difference between A's date/time and B's date/time must be no more than 12 hours"? Please clarify.

Comment: The date shall also be considered. Yes, "the difference between A's date/time and B's date/time must be no more than 12 hours".

Comment: Okay, I've altered my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to combine records of one table with records of another, you'd **join** the tables:

As you store date and time as strings, you must convert them to DATE (i.e. a datetime value) first. Then subtract one from the other, so as to get the difference in days. 12 hours = 0.5 days.

```
select 
  a.date, a.time, a.col1, a.col2,
  b.date, b.time, b.col1, b.col2
from a
join b on a.col1 = b.col2 and a.col2 = b.col1
 and abs(to_date(a.date || a.time , 'yyyymmddhh24miss') -
         to_date(b.date || b.time , 'yyyymmddhh24miss')) <= 0.5;
```

It is uncommon by the way to store the date and the time in two separate varchar columns. Usually you would simply use a DATE column which contains both the date and the time.

Comment: more than just "uncommon"; it's uncommonly bad

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/be1f78/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE A ( "Date", "Time", Col1, Col2 ) AS
          SELECT '20150818', '000256', 'AAAA', 'BBBB' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '20150818', '000456', 'AAAA', 'CCCC' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE B ( "Date", "Time", Col1, Col2 ) AS
          SELECT '20150820', '000359', 'BBBB', 'AAAA' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '20150818', '000259', 'BBBB', 'AAAA' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '20150818', '001459', 'CCCC', 'AAAA' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   A
       INNER JOIN
       B
       ON (
             TO_DATE( a."Date" || a."Time", 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' ) BETWEEN TO_DATE( b."Date" || b."Time", 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' ) - INTERVAL '12' HOUR AND TO_DATE( b."Date" || b."Time", 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' ) + INTERVAL '12' HOUR
         AND a.Col1 = b.Col2
         AND a.Col2 = b.Col1
       )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/be1f78/4/0)**:

```
|     Date |   Time | COL1 | COL2 |     Date |   Time | COL1 | COL2 |
|----------|--------|------|------|----------|--------|------|------|
| 20150818 | 000256 | AAAA | BBBB | 20150818 | 000259 | BBBB | AAAA |
| 20150818 | 000456 | AAAA | CCCC | 20150818 | 001459 | CCCC | AAAA |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
select * from A inner join (select * from B where b.time <= 12 hours) C
on  C.Col1 = A.Col2 and C.Col2 = A.Col1
```